# Execute async request every N seconds while websocket keeps streaming python

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

Using Async with websocket and web requests, how does one continuously watch data from websocket while also, with N seconds interval, updating data from web request.

I've tried different versions of

```py
async def websocket_stream():
    while True:
      get_data_from_stream()
      do_stuff_with_data()

async def web_requests():
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
      for n in list_of_things:
        html= client.get('www.webpage.com/stuff')
        do_other_stuff_with_data(html)

async def do_sometimes(timeout, stuff):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
        await stuff()
async def do_nonstop(stuff):
    while True:
        await stuff()

taskone=asyncio.create_task(do_nonstop(web_stream))
tasktwo=asyncio.create_task(do_sometimes(10, web_request()))
```

Which obviously doesnt work and just streams web_streams.

How do I define so that `web_request()` only does one loop thru `list_of_things` and then sleeps for N seconds while `web_streams()` websocket keeps streaming?